# how to support an apk for both mobile and tablet

Tags: android

```
    i am developed one apk for mobile(4 inch).. 
    same apk i can put tablet means total gui changed ..
    i want my apk can put any mobile or any tablet . the gui cannot changed .. 
    please how to achieve this problem..please suggest me
```

what ever the screen resolution   my application ui can change the according the resolution

Comment: You should read on supporting multiple screen resolutions. Start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

See
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

There are all infos you need to know to make sure your app look great on all devices. It's barely not that easy as you think.

Comment: there are four screen sizes are there small,normal,large,and extra large..i understand that much ..can explain parametrically means main.xml how can re size automatically

Comment: i searched now. i am getting what means i want crate four folders like layout-small,layout-large,layout-xlarge. then i can put main.xml to all folder means i can get according to the screen i gui can changes. but i have one doubt ..if i crate one main.xml for mobile ..same main.xml i can put layout-xlarge folder means the gui changes according to the tablet.is it correct or not ..please tell me

Comment: "most" tablets will use the layout out of "xlarge" (depending on the size of the tablet). in the main.xml in xlarge you can set higher paddings or sth to make it look better on tablets.